# Failed to load sap/m/label.js

Tags: label, sapui5

This is really strange. I have developed an app using SAP Web IDE Personal edition. Application works fine. Deployed it on my ABAP backend, everything OK, same thing when I deployed it on my QAS system. So far so good.

Deployed the application on SAP Web IDE Full-stack on the Cloud. Configured Cloud Connector, set up destinations in SCP and ran the application from there. Everything OK with the main screen (lots of components, among them a table). As soon as I clicked on one of the rows to navigate to my detailed view, app crashed reporting a `404 error` for file `sap/m/label.js`.

Changed bootstrapping, replacing the reference to my libraries with a reference to the Cloud Platform ones [SAP UI core libraries](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js)

Got the same error, along with a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` (according to my poor knowledge shouldn't see it when running Chrome with no security options but whatever). In a few words, my app seems to have an issue with `sap/m/label.js`, no matter which kind of bootstrapping I use, while in my local environment (1.44.31) everything works fine. Any idea where I should look?

Exception:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'sap/m/label.js' from ../resources/sap/m/label.js: 404 - Not Found
    at p1 (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3274)
    at Object.q.sap.require (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3840)
    at f (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:1949)
    at k (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:2798)
    at h (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:2754)
    at g (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:2497)
    at Q (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:5485)
    at P (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:5101)
    at k (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:6172)
    at h (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:572:2754)
```

Comment: There's a good chance `Label` is case sensitive.

Comment: @Jorg: it's indeed case sensitive but all the elements are defined as <Label... and the file (was able to locate it in the Personal Web IDE folders) is called Label.js as well. The fact that the system is looking for a label.js is what confuses me.

Comment: @Jorg: You are absolutely right (thank you). Found one <label... among all <Label... elements, changed it and worked. BUT now I'm even more confused. How the same code runs in the backend and from Personal Web IDE without crashing?

Comment: Hi Greg, does your local environment and abap system run on Windows?

Comment: @Jorg: Hello, my local environment is indeed a window machine but my back-end system is SunOS (call me Unix), both of them working correctly without the correction. Interesting here that I almost all of the Labels were defined as <Label... except one that was found as <label... The bizarre thing? This one is also visible.

Comment: In windows, filenames are not case sensitive. Meaning, LABEL.js is the same as Label.js etc. On *nix environments, Label.js en LABEL.js are two different files... SCP runs on on linux (my money is on SUSE...). Maybe the files hosted on the SAP machine itself are not case sensitive, since the UI5 libraries are hosted from the mime repository... I have no other explanation

Comment: @Jorg: Aware of the Windows behavior, what confuses me is the behavior of the back-end with the app having been deployed directly from my "client" (Personal IDE). Your explanation is the only one making sense, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check if you have a < label > instead of < Label > somewhere in your Detail View

By the way, for the CORS issue (allow origin...) you should fix it setting up a "destination" equivalent in your back-end side. This can be done with the Web Dispatcher. Setting it as a reverse proxy, so whenever the web dispatcher receives a call in certain URL (the one you choose) it redirects it to the UI5 CDN. Then the WD receive the UI5 core files in the response and automatically send them to your browser, so your browser "thinks" the files come from the WD which has the same host:port as all the other requests. Therefore no CORS issue

Solve the CORS first. If you have the CORS issue there, it will never work.

Comment: Hello. Destination was already configured and regarding the CORS issue I'm running from a Chrome browser with options "--disable-web-security --user-data-dir" which I've read that bypass the problem. Indeed there was one <label> element, as soon as this was corrected App ran correctly. Problem solved, still one question remains. How the exact same code is running both in my Personal Dev environment and my Back-end system (where it's already deployed) without a problem.

Comment: First. When you say 'Destination already configured' I guess you did it in the Cloud Platform. That's good if you deploy your app in CP or running the app while developing. But you need to understand what's the CORS issue. It appears when you try to load resources from different hosts. For example from your ABAP system and the ui5.hana.ondeman.com. Destinations proxy the calls so you decide which servers your app can access. So the browser thinks all resources come from CP. Once you deploy your app in your ABAP system, your CP account is not in the scope any more, the same as destinations.

Comment: You need to configure then the WD. So it acts as proxy for your app calls, when the app is hosted in your ABAP system. The same way as destinations do for your CP hosted apps.

Comment: If you disable the whole CORS, your app will be able to load files from any server, which is very dangerous. A malicious JS file can scrap all the data showed in your screen as well as get input data (e.g. email and password) and send it to an external server

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your last question, but if you have a < label > it won't work in any of your environments. It will broke as soon as you lose the file containing that wrong tag.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the CORS explanation, I'm aware of it. App is running on the ABAP backend, accessible to and used only in local intranet, CORS enabled and only my browser runs this way. Uploaded it in SAP Cloud Platform just to check compatibility with my environment along with the additional features provided. I just wouldn't expected it occurring in SCP with destination in place, SCC active and browser configured at the same time. Funfact? Occurred only on the label.js case and disappeared after correction (<label.. -> <Label...). However, thanks again for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Was working in SAP Web IDE Personal edition and worked when deployed in the backend, Issue occurred (correctly) when I uploaded it to play with SCP. Explanation by Jorg above is possibly the answer.